# How to sort data according to the date in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to **write a bash program** that sorts the data according to the date and displays the name of the person who recently joined the organization.

I have an **employees.txt** file with data in it with **delimiter |**. But when I am trying to sort the data using sort command like

`sort -t'|' -k5,5 employees.txt | head -1 | cut -d'|' -f2`

this is only sorting according to the first column of the whole date i.e DD-MM-YYYY sorting only on DD.

**employees.txt File data format**

`ID | NAME | POST | DEPARTMENT | JOINING DATE | SALARY`

```
101 | Jhon McClare | Manager | Content | 23-02-2001 | 83000
102 | Alena Croft | Snr. Manager | Accounts | 01-01-2019 | 88888
103 | Jeremy | Director | Sales | 20-03-2012 | 89786
104 | Williams | Manager | Marketing | 23-06-2001 | 73000
```

The above image should give **Alena Croft** as the answer.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I have edited the input data, hope it helps. Isn't there any way to sort this type of date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant field be must rendered suitable for sorting, that is, in the form of YYYY-MM-DD, using a utility such as `sed` or `awk`. For example, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\3-\2-\1/' employees.txt |
sort -r -t'|' -k5,5 | head -n1 | cut -d'|' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to change the format of date to YYYY-MM-DD.

```
$ cat people.txt | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/\3\-\2\-\1/' | sort -t'|' -k5,5r | head -1 | cut -d'|' -f2
 Alena Croft
```

Also note that when sorting we need to do in reverse order (descending order) since we want the most recent date.